# Power Bi - Custom Connector Oauth2 (fhir)

Tags: oauth-2.0, powerbi, powerquery, hl7-fhir, powerbi-custom-data-connector

We've Smile CDR fhir server that supports oauth2. We're trying to connect to it using power bi, for this we're creating custom connector. We've added power bi as a client in Smile CDR. In the code we're passing every details however, we're getting 404 error.

Code and ss can be found in the below link.

https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Power-Query/Custom-Connector-Oauth2/m-p/2198649#M65049

Comment: If this is from a PBI Desktop application, enable the OAuth logging as follows:
PowerBI Desktop - Options - Diagnostics - Enable Tracing.

 Once this is enabled, the logs would be captured here:

%localappdata%\Microsoft\Power BI Desktop\Traces , in a file with name like "Mashup%%%" where the exact error message will be captured for review.